# Github API searching in repositories where user has read, write or admin permissions

Tags: github-api

I am using the Github API to show repositories to the user.
Specifically those, where the user has `:read`, `:write` or `:admin` access. Or in other words, repos owned by the user, repos where they are collaborators, or repos they can access through an org membership.

The following API provides exactly that:
https://api.github.com/user/repos

However, it does NOT allow for searching. Say the user wants to search in this list for a specific repo, then this API endpoint does not enable that.

Github's search APIs are under `/search/...`
And this API seems promising:
https://api.github.com/search/repositories.

However, I did not find a way to filter the repositories to only show those where the user has `:read`, `:write` or `:admin` access.

Is there any API endpoint where I can retrieve the list of repos with the following condition:

- repos owned by the user
- repos where they are collaborators
- or repos they can access through an org membership.

While also being able to search within this API endpoint for specific repos by name.

Comment: GitHub APIs don't seem to have a search feature for repositories that the user has specific access privileges to. But you already have the repositories that the user has access to, so you can do some filtering on the client side.